# when i send data through my api i get this Error TypeError at /api/add/ Object of type UserInfo is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

i have two models one is for *User* and another is *UserInfo*, i am inserting additional information of user to a model that have foreignkey relationship with user model.

when i add additional information to the api ,the data is getting stored but i get error instead of response.

**serilaizers.py**

```
class UserCreateSerializerCustom(UserCreateSerializer):
    
    class Meta(UserCreateSerializer.Meta,):
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'username',
            'password',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'phone',         
        )

## User Additional Info Serializers
class UserAdditionalSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserCreateSerializerCustom()
    class Meta:
        model = UserInfo
        fields = (
            'user',
            'address',
            'zipcode',
        )
```

**Views.py**

```
class UserAdditionalView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):   
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAdditionalSerializers
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
       
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(" ")[1]
        print(token)
        us = Token.objects.get(key=token).user

        user1 = User.objects.get(email=us)

        user,_ = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user1)
        user.address=request.POST['address']
        user.zipcode=request.POST['zipcode']
        user.save()
        return Response({'user':user})
```

**urls.py**

```
path('add/',views.UserAdditionalView.as_view()),
```

**models.py**

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # username = None
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=50,unique=True)
    #phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$')
    #phone = PhoneNumberField(unique=True,blank=False,null=False)
    phone =  models.CharField(max_length=17,blank=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'phone',
        'username',
    ]

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'

    def get_username(self):
        return self.email
class UserInfo(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

**My expected response is**

```
 {
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "username": "test",
        "first_name": "test",
        "last_name": "test",
        "phone": "+1(123)-456-7890"
    },
    "address": "kjbnjklqnja",
    "zipcode": "69996"
}
```

in order to get the required response what should i do..?

i'm finding user based on token send with the request.
i'm just started in rest api's world,
Can any one help me out .

Comment: can you post your stack trace as well as your UserCreateSerializer

Comment: I have imported that serializer from djoser package. https://github.com/sunscrapers/djoser/blob/master/djoser/serializers.py. sorry, i didnt understand the term stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to update an object in post method manually as serializer take care of it and before sending data in `Response` you have to serialize the data

so

```
from rest_framework import status

class UserAdditionalView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):   
    queryset = UserInfo.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAdditionalSerializers
    # authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication)

    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
       
        token = request.META['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'].split(" ")[1]
        us = Token.objects.get(key=token).user
        user1 = User.objects.get(email=us)
        user,_ = UserInfo.objects.get_or_create(user=user1)
        serializer = UserAdditionalSerializers(data=request.data,instance=user)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data,status=status.HTTP_201_OK)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: it gives the following error, AssertionError at /api/add/
Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`.

Comment: it gives the following error "user": ["This field is required."],but when i use following code it works . user.address=request.POST['address']
        user.zipcode=request.POST['zipcode']
        user.save()
        serializer = UserAdditionalSerializers(user)
        return Response(serializer.data)    ,

Comment: Okay got it because in the request.data you'll get only address and zipcode

Comment: the main thing is, in response we must have to send serialized data like `serializer.data`. Hope you get it.

Comment: To make serializer valid what should i do..?, and Is it a good practice to get user info from token.?

Comment: No, you should validate token from user credential instead of getting user details from token

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220530/discussion-between-pruthvi-barot-and-ashil).